# c++ return array of unsigned char

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I have this function:

```
    unsigned char* encrypt_decrypt( unsigned char* text,unsigned char* pass)
    {
       unsigned char *s=(unsigned char*)malloc(strlen((char*)text+1)*sizeof(unsigned char));
       int length=strlen((char*)text);
       printf("chestii:%d",sizeof(s));
       for(int i=0;i<length;i++)
       {

        s[i]=text[i]^pass[i];
        printf("text:%d\n",text[i]);
        printf("pass:%d\n",pass[i]);
        printf("cript:%d\n",s[i]);
       }
       s[length]='\0';

       return s;
    }
```

The text and pass have the exact length and the s pointer should have the same length as the text at the end of the function.For example let's say that the text and pass have 26 characters.I don't know why but at the end of the for instruction,the length of the s pointer is only 10.I allocated enough memory and I think i put 26 elements in s.Please help me figure out why strlen(s) is only 10 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

strlen counts up to a 0 byte so if a letter is in common in text and pass it will terminate the string early because text[i]^pass[i]==0 if text[i]==pass[i].

Comment: how do you suggest I  solve this problem ?How can I make the string continue even if this sort of thing happens ?

Comment: Pass it around your program as a structure containing a pointer to the bytes + a field containing the length of the string.